# What is this error- "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'audio.flac' ", i am trying to use the google voice recognition api for python

Tags: python-2.7, 32-bit, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, ioerror

Basically i want to convert speech to text, so I am trying to use the google voice recognition api for python.

This is the code which i'm trying to run-

```
from pygsr import Pygsr
speech = Pygsr()
speech.record(3) # duration in seconds (3)
phrase, complete_response = speech.speech_to_text('es_ES')
print phrase # This is the required output
```

I've installed all the modules correctly, so probably nothing is wrong with the modules, i am getting the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/google_voice.py", line 4, in <module>
    phrase, complete_response = speech.speech_to_text('es_ES') # select the language
  File "C:/Python\pygsr\__init__.py", line 49, in speech_to_text
    audio = open(file_upload, "rb").read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'audio.flac'
```

Can somebody please tell me what am i missing. 
Or please suggest any good speech to text conversion method for python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the sox tool installed which converts recorded wav to flac, you can see in line in pygsr sources: system("sox %s -t wav -r 48000 -t flac %s.flac" % (self.file, self.file)). Make sure that sox works for you and it can create flac files.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit ?